# Are these two datasets interval?

Tags: dataset

I have two dataset: population density and case fatality rate.
Population density is measured as number of people living in an area divided by that area size in square miles (number of people/area size).
Case fatality rate is calculated as total death from an infection divided by total number of infections (total death/total infection).
Are population density and case fatality rate intervals?

Comment: Presumably you mean of "interval data type."  But could you explain why the answer would be relevant to any kind of data analysis or investigation?

Comment: Both datasets take only non-negative values.

Comment: @whuber yes I meant are they interval data type. I want to find if there is a correlation between them. I use population density as the independent value.

Comment: @BruceET yes. So are they interval data type?

Comment: For assessing relationships or correlations, it is superfluous to determine the data type.

Comment: @whuber for some reason the person I report to needs know the data type

Answer (score 1):

Both population density and case fatality rate are based on a ratio of a necessarily non-negative value to a necessarily positive value. That's the definition of a [ratio-scale measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Ratio_scale).

As comments have pointed out, you don't need to distinguish interval from ratio data types to do correlations.* Also, [correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation#Symmetry_property) are generally considered to be symmetric between 2 variables, without a defined "independent" variable. That distinction becomes important when you are doing regression.

---

*I don't find the "interval" measurement type as defined by Stevens to be very helpful, except to provide a warning about taking ratios. I suspect that most users of this site would lean toward the [Mosteller/Tukey typology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement#Mosteller_and_Tukey%27s_typology_(1977)), perhaps extending it in particular cases with things like cyclic data.